# check first frame on embedding flutter activity

Tags: android, flutter

On iOS there is a method called `setFlutterViewDidRenderCallback` that can be used to know when the first frame has been drawn. Is there a way to the same thing in an embedding FlutterActivity (`io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging into the flutter source code on github I figured I can override the method `onFlutterUiDisplayed` to get the desired behavior.

Comment: can you please provide a complete example?